# How to make Binary Search Tree with Object as node?

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree, icomparable

Is there a way you can have a Binary Search Tree with Object nodes, that store multiple values, and which have the ability to treat one of these values as the "main" variable that will be used for comparison when sorting (balancing) the tree.

Example:

Tree = `Artist` Collection

- each `Artist` is a Node with properties such as `Name`, `Age` etc, and
- `Name` is the "main" property that is used for comparison when sorting/balancing the tree

This is what I've tried for my node definition, but I need help with the afore-mentioned features:

```
    class Artist<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T name;
    private T members;

    public Artist<T> Left, Right;

    public Artist(T Name, T Members)
    {
        name = Name;
        members = Members;
        Left = null;
        Right = null;
    }
    public T Name
    {
        set { name = value; }
        get { return name; }
    }
    public T Members
    {
        set { members = value; }
        get { return members; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do it. Do you have a specific question about how it's done? What have you tried?

Comment: Yes I managed to make BSTree that contains one value (data) but unable to think of a way to add another variable that can be searched as well

Comment: Steve I mean Balanced, sorry for mistake,

Comment: @SteveWellens http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree_sort.

Comment: @user2154803 when you're directing a comment to someone, you should use their username (including the @ prefix) and they'll get a notification that you've replied to them.

Answer (score 0):

To make one of your member values the "main" one for sorting...

You should implement the `IComparable` interface directly on your `Artist` class, such that these nodes are directly comparable.  This allows you to then control *how* instances of this class are compared.

To do this, you basically just run a comparison on the member you're interested in, and pass that result back as the result of your object's comparison.

Eg:

```
class Artist : IComparable
{
    /* Your Artist specific implementation here */
    private string name;
    private int age;
    ...

    /* Implementation of IComparable */
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Artist compareToObj = (Artist)obj;

        // Comparison by name.
        return this.name.CompareTo(compareToObj.name);

        // And if you wanted to do the comparison by eg age:
        // return this.age.CompareTo(compareToObj.age);
    }
}
```

---

Regarding your use of a generic node:

I'm not sure why you've made your `Artist` class generic - I would assume that an `Artist` is not generic as you have known properties etc for an artist..  At least, I can't see that that's of any use in the context of this question.  Your `BinarySearchTree` implementation *should* be generic, however, such that it can be a tree of `Artist`s, `Car`s, `Gerbil`s or whatever other `Object` you see fit to use in a BST.

But if you *do* need a generic eg `MyGenericNode` class, that'll allow nodes of any type, then yes you'd make it generic, and ensure whatever type is specified is IComparable as per your code.  But there's no way for your `MyGenericNode` to "know" what member of `<T>` to compare on, except to rely on `<T>`'s specific implementation of `.CompareTo()`.

If you wanted to get "fancy" (read: messy, complicated, overkill...), I *think* you could write your own interface eg `IComparisonMemberSpecifiable` that allows you to pass to it the name of an `IComparable` member on which your node comparison occurs.  `<T>` must also implement your new interface in addition to `IComparable`.  Then your `MyGenericNode` would use reflection to "find" the specified member within `<T>` and do a comparison on that. I would *highly* recommend you don't do this - just put this here as an "answer" to your question ;-)

But really - it's your tree that needs to be generic to accept nodes of different classes.  Your node class need/should not be generic IMHO.